# How could I solve "no module named proxy" error?

Tags: python, google-crawlers

I'm learning about crawlers, and after a few basic ones I tried downloading the google scholar crawler master from github to see how it runs, after a few errors that I could fix, I ran into a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'proxy'` error (`middleware.py` file, `from proxy import PROXIES` line is the issue).

This code has had a few problems containing solutions that are no longer supported/advised in python 3.x versions, including modules that have since been renamed/moved, but I was unable to find out if this is the case for this as well, would appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about this https://github.com/geekan/google-scholar-crawler crawler:

I just tried to run it on Python 2.7 and had no problems with it. A brief look at misc module told me, that there is a possible problem with relative imports (some information about it may be found in this quesion [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)).

So, the short answer is simply to use python 2.7 as it will allow to concentrate on understanding how scrapy crawlers work instead of understanding language version differences.

UPD: also make sure to remove all of the `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` breakpoints in the code